# Show that derivate directional doesn't exist

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Let be $f(x, y)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}x+y, & x=0 \lor y=0 \\ 1, & x \neq 0 \land y \neq 0\end{array} .\right.$

Show that  $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)=1 .$

But that the directional derivative
$\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}(0,0)$ does not exist for $u=(a, b)$ with  $a \neq 0$ y $b \neq 0$

I did

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)=\lim_ {h \to 0} \frac{f(h+0,0)-f(0,0)}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{h+0-0-0}{h} = 1 $ and the same for $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$

The for the directional I did:

$Duf(0,0)=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(ha,hb)-f(0,0)}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0}=\frac{1-(0+0)}{h}$ and this limit is divergent

Is this right?

Comment: Another way to do this is to note that, for  y= ax, $a\ne 0$, f(x,y)= f(x, ax)= ax+ x= (a+1)x for x not 0 but for x= 0, f(0, 0)= 1.  That function is not continuous at x= 0 so is not differentiable there.

Comment: @user247327 thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are right the limit diverges or, more precisely, both right and left limits diverges with different sign

$$\lim_{h \to 0^+}=\frac{1}{h}=\infty$$

$$\lim_{h \to 0^-}=\frac{1}{h}=-\infty$$